# create a readonly connection to MySQL?

Tags: .net, mysql

I looked at the [MySql Connection Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) and it doesnt seem to be there. Is there a way to create a read only connection/command for .NET? With SQLite i could specify `read only=true` to do this. What can i do with MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `SELECT` privileges to a user using `GRANT` eg:

```
GRANT SELECT ON db_base.* TO db_user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd';
```

**Resources:**

**[The MySQL Access Privilege System](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privilege-system.html)**
**[MySQL grant](http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/grant.html)**

Answer (score 5):

You can create a user with SELECT only privileges